# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS installation from usb crash with kernel panic Bad RIP value

Tags: system-installation

This is the first time I'm trying to install Ubuntu.
I have an old Acer laptop with Windows installed and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 from a bootable USB.
The installation crashed with `Bad RIP value`.

I also tried adding the `noapic` flag but a similar error occurred.

I recreated the USB several times and checked the USB sha1 - all ok.

Thanks in advance.